# Joining three tables in SQL with duplicated column names

Tags: sql

I have three tables in SQL which I need to join them together and this is a simplified version:

**Table 1 Columns**

```
Person ID (pID)
Fav Soccer Team (favST)
Fav Soccer Player (favSP)
```

**Table 2 Columns**

```
Person ID (pID) 
Fav Soccer Team (favST) 
Fav Soccer Player (favSP)
```

**Table 3 Columns**

```
Person ID (person_ID)
Person Name (pName)
```

The problem is that each person may appear in both Table 1 and Table 2. You can take for example that Table 1 reflects the favourite team and player in 2017, and Table 2 reflects the favourite team and player in 2018.

I have to create a query which will join them all and show

**Result Columns**

```
Person ID (pID) 
Person Name (pName)
Favourite Soccer Team (favST) 
Favourite Soccer Player (favSP)
Table1/Table2 <--- which table this row of data is from
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Fix that design and have table 1 and 2 become one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select
  Table3.person_ID,
  Table3.pName,
  X.favST,
  X.favSP,
  X.tname
From
  Table3
Left join
  (
  Select
    PID,
    FavST,
    FavSP,
    'Table1' as tname
   From
    Table1
  Union
  Select
    PID,
    FavST,
    FavSP,
    'Table2' as tname
   From
    Table2
  )X on x.pId = table3.person_ID;
```